# "Avoid asking for clarification to answers" - What does it mean?

Tags: discussion, answers

I [answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180023/klenkes-construction-of-brownian-motion) my first question today. A message popped up with [guidelines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nivz.jpg). "Avoid asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers." Really?? Seems draconian to me, unless i miss something. What if the answer isn't clear?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The idea of this automatic message is that answers should be good, relatively self-contained, objective responses to a question. When the guidelines suggest avoiding asking for clarification or responding to other answers, they don't mean to *avoid asking for clarification at all costs.* Instead, they mean don't ask for clarification *in your answer.*

There is a comment system for asking for clarification, responding to answers, etc. In fact, in the faq it is [mentioned](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) that comments should and will be used for clarification, for example.

But this might be very confusing, because there is a [reputation limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) to be able to comment on questions that aren't your own. You need 50 reputation, so you're almost there.

So to end, one can ask for clarification on answers, but this should be done in *comments* as opposed to *other answers.*

Comment: Thanks. Now it makes sense...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. [I asked on Meta SE for the message to be clarified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143682/first-answer-guidelines-message-avoid-asking-for-clarification-to-answers-is-c) to avoid confusing future users.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: Great, thanks!